# Why does the result of OpenSSL differ for TLS versions?

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, tls1.2, rhel

Our Java application is running on the RHEL 8.5 OS platform. The application makes use of Apache HTTPd and the Amazon Corretto JDK 1.8.0_322 release. And we have added the below code in the **ssl.conf** file to enhance the security level.

```
SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:AES256-CCM:DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM
```

In the above part, we have enabled Only TLSv1.2.

The below OpenSSL commands are displaying different results.

**Scenario 1:**

```
[root@test ~]# openssl ciphers -v | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq 
SSLv3
TLSv1
TLSv1.2
TLSv1.3
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
[root@test ~]# /usr/bin/openssl ciphers -v
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
AES256-CCM              TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
AES128-GCM-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
AES128-CCM              TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
AES256-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
AES128-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES256-CCM          TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES128-CCM          TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256   TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES256-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES128-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
[root@test ~]#
```

**Scenario 3:**

```
[root@test ~]# openssl s_client -connect <IP_ADDRESS>:8443 -tls1
CONNECTED(00000003)
139679030896448:error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 70
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 104 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1662128840
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

**Scenario 4:**

```
[root@test ~]# nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 8443 <IP_ADDRESS>
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-09-02 20:02 IST
mass_dns: warning: Unable to open /etc/resolv.conf. Try using --system-dns or specify valid servers with --dns-servers
mass_dns: warning: Unable to determine any DNS servers. Reverse DNS is disabled. Try using --system-dns or specify valid servers with --dns-servers
Nmap scan report for XXXXX (IP_ADDRESS)
Host is up (0.00067s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE  VERSION
8443/tcp open  ssl/http Apache httpd
|_http-server-header: Apache
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|_  least strength: A
MAC Address: 00:50:56:A7:92:7B (VMware)

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 12.90 seconds
```

In the above results, scenario 1 and scenario 2 is showing that TLSv1 is also enabled. But scenario 3 and scenario 4 is showing that only TLSv1.2 is enabled.

We are confused with the above results because of whether TLSv1 is enabled or not.

Please help us with the answers to the below queries.

1. Why is the OpenSSL command displaying different results(Scenario 2 & 4)?
2. How do I disable TLSv1 if it is enabled?
3. How to confirm that TLSv1 is disabled on our server for Linux?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just mixing up a few things.

ssl.conf is Apache specific, and your tests number 3 and 4 verify the Apache config just fine. All good!

Tests 1 and 2 are for the openssl command line tool: it's quite separate to Apache, so nothing to worry about.

As an aside, the [qualys ssl tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) is useful for verifying a whole raft of TLS settings (not just the protocol) and the [Mozilla SSL site](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/) is useful for giving you secure configs to start from.

Comment: @Buffoonism...Still have a doubt with OpenSSL Commands. In test number 2 and 3, the result differs. And please let me know whether my server is enabled for TLS1 or not.

Comment: so tests 1 & 2 are just telling you what's in your fridge that can be made into a meal (but not what's in your meal), and tests 2 & 3 tell you what is actually in your raviolli. ;)

Comment: if you want to be 100% confident though, go to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and enter your web site. it'll connect, test it thoroughly, and tell you what is there!

Comment: Our Application is in Private Network. Can't able to check with ssllabs.com. Could you please suggest another alternate option?

Comment: tests 3 & 4 have already confirmed the protocol is disabled: all good!